# how to navigate to login after successful register in android

Tags: android, web-services, android-intent, android-activity

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
       registerUser();
    }



private void registerUser() {
           if (editTextName.getText().toString().equals("")) {

        editTextName.setError("Pleas fill this field");
               editTextName.requestFocus();
    }
           else if(editTextEmail.getText().toString().equals(""))
           {
               editTextEmail.setError("Enter your email");
               editTextEmail.requestFocus();
           }
    else if (!validateEmail(editTextEmail.getText().toString())) {
        editTextEmail.setError("Invalid EmailId");
        editTextEmail.requestFocus();

    }

    else if(editTextPassword.getText().toString().equals(""))
    {
        editTextPassword.setError("Enter a Password");
    }
           else if(editTextPhone.getText().toString().equals(""))
           {
               editTextPhone.setError("Enter your mobile number");
               editTextPhone.requestFocus();

           }
    else if (!validatePhone(editTextPhone.getText().toString())) {
        editTextPhone.setError("Invalid Mobile Number");
        editTextPhone.requestFocus();
    }
    else {
        String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
        String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
        String phone = editTextPhone.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
        register(name, email, password, phone);

    }
}
private void register(String name, String email, String password, String phone ) {

    String urlSuffix = "?name="+name+"&email="+email+"&password="+password+"&phone="+phone;
    class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(SignUpActivity.this, "Please Wait",null, true, true);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String s = params[0];
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(REGISTER_URL+s);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                String result;

                result = bufferedReader.readLine();

                return result;
            }catch(Exception e){
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    RegisterUser ru = new RegisterUser();
    ru.execute(urlSuffix);
}
```

Here are my 2 doubts:

1. I need to navigate to login page after the user has successfully registered, else should remain in the same page.
2. Need to dismiss edit text field when the user is successfully registered. when the user already exist the edit text field should not be dismissed.

Comment: in postExecute method you should check response and according to response you can nevigate to login page or clear edit text

Comment: can u pls suggest a code of sample for this

Comment: if response 1 means i need to navigate to loginpage

Comment: show your response here.

Comment: For your second doubt you need to check from your response that whether the user is already exists or not..!! According to that response you will need to display message to user.

Comment: whats wrong in my answer and the new accepted one, your unchecked mine after checking the write one?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to add Intent with Flag into `onPostExecute()` method of  `AsyncTask` as below :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    registerUser();
}


private void registerUser() {
    if (editTextName.getText().toString().equals("")) {

        editTextName.setError("Pleas fill this field");
        editTextName.requestFocus();
    } else if (editTextEmail.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        editTextEmail.setError("Enter your email");
        editTextEmail.requestFocus();
    } else if (!validateEmail(editTextEmail.getText().toString())) {
        editTextEmail.setError("Invalid EmailId");
        editTextEmail.requestFocus();

    } else if (editTextPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        editTextPassword.setError("Enter a Password");
    } else if (editTextPhone.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        editTextPhone.setError("Enter your mobile number");
        editTextPhone.requestFocus();

    } else if (!validatePhone(editTextPhone.getText().toString())) {
        editTextPhone.setError("Invalid Mobile Number");
        editTextPhone.requestFocus();
    } else {
        String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
        String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
        String phone = editTextPhone.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
        register(name, email, password, phone);

    }
}

private void register(String name, String email, String password, String phone) {

    String urlSuffix = "?name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&password=" + password + "&phone=" + phone;
    class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(SignUpActivity.this, "Please Wait", null, true, true);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intLogin = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            intLogin.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intLogin);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String s = params[0];
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(REGISTER_URL + s);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                String result;

                result = bufferedReader.readLine();

                return result;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    RegisterUser ru = new RegisterUser();
    ru.execute(urlSuffix);
}
```

Comment: thanks . but it's getting redirected if the email alredy exists. if the emaiid already exists it should not be redirected to loginactivity . can suggest a solution

Comment: You need to check condition using result before doing `Intent` into `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: try{
            if (s.equals("1")){
                Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intLogin = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
                intLogin.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intLogin);
            }
                    else if(s.equals("0"))
            {
                Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Email Already Exixts", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }    i

Comment: i tried if (s.equals{"1")) that is new user its getting success and can navigate to next page.  but (s.equals("0")) is email already already exists. but when is use this the progress is loading i cant get the error ms  what to do.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        loading.dismiss();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```